# Storing the values from structure to file

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to store distance between two residues using following code :

```
f = open('%s.txt' % fileName, 'w')
print(residue1,residue2,distance)
f.write(line)
```

The print command shows following output :

```
<Residue   U het=  resseq=63 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 66.809425
<Residue   G het=  resseq=64 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 71.63533
<Residue   C het=  resseq=65 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 76.931366
<Residue   G het=  resseq=66 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 81.664375
<Residue   A het=  resseq=67 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 84.5027
<Residue   U het=  resseq=68 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 87.20471
<Residue   A het=  resseq=69 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 82.4701
<Residue   A het=  resseq=70 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 76.94348
<Residue   G het=  resseq=71 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 76.04107
<Residue   C het=  resseq=72 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 82.2956
<Residue   C het=  resseq=73 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 87.42678
<Residue   A het=  resseq=74 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 92.075035
<Residue   U het=  resseq=75 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 94.59299
<Residue   G het=  resseq=76 icode= > <Residue   A het=  resseq=11 icode= > 94.36213
```

When I am editing the code to add lines to store output into the file :

```
f = open('%s.txt' % fileName, 'w')
print(residue1,residue2,distance)
line = str(residue1)+','+str(residue2)+','+str(distance)
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

I am getting the following error :

```
    model = structure[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 41, in __getitem__
    return self.child_dict[id]
KeyError: 0
```

How to resolve it ?

Update :

```
f = open('%s.txt' % fileName, 'w')
print(residue1.get_id(),',',residue2.get_id(),',',distance)
line = f"{residue1.get_id()}, {residue2.get_id()}, {distance}"
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

This line runs for one time with the following output in output file:

```
(' ', 122, ' '), (' ', 11, ' '), 144.1501007080078
```

and then terminates back with error